# What should i give for bundle id

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I created a new project in ionic using the command `ionic start new`. What should I give for bundle id? I am new to ionic and ios.

```
ionic start new=== BUILD TARGET MyApp OF PROJECT MyApp WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'io.ionic.starter' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'io.ionic.starter'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
```

Comment: please use search function for stuff like that, you also have ionic manual for that

Comment: @Lu_ can we create bundle identifier for free

Comment: Yes, you can go with your bundle ID, but to sign a project and for example test it on device you need to create developer profile

Comment: @Lu_ sir can i do it for free for testing in my device

Comment: you can not on iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **bundle ID or bundle identifier** uniquely identifies an application in the Apple store or Google Play Store. This means that no two applications can have the same bundle identifier. To avoid conflicts, it is encouraged that developers use [reverse domain name notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation) for choosing an application's bundle identifier.

> Eg: If your domain name is **www.example.com**, then your bundle ID
>   can be **com.example**.

Specific to your case, *'io.ionic.starter'* or *'com.example'* are default bundle IDs that come along while creating Ionic or Cordova projects. These IDs are not unique and any submission to the respective stores would be rejected. Please choose a bundle ID as per the description above or anything that is relevant, yet unique to your application.

Comment: Thanks Nidhin Joseph for detailed explanation